# org-capture template with file local variables

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, file-local-variables

I'm trying to set up a capture that automatically deactivates the undo-tree history saving in an encrypted file by setting [file local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).
When I call the capture and have entered the filename the following error happens:

> error("Capture template `%s': %s" "E" "Template is not a valid Org
> entry or tree")

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("E" "Encrypted File" entry (file my-org-capture-ask-for-filename)
                                 "-*- undo-tree-auto-save-history: nil; epa-file-encrypt-to: nil; -*-

* %i%?")))
```

The error disappears once I remove the file variables:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("E" "Encrypted File" entry (file my-org-capture-ask-for-filename)
                                 "* %i%?")))
```

Do I have to escape the file variable line somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out. I had to specify "plain" instead of "entry" as [type](https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html), otherwise org-capture expects an org mode node, with a headline:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("E" "Encrypted File" plain (file my-org-capture-ask-for-filename)
                                 "-*- undo-tree-auto-save-history: nil; epa-file-encrypt-to: nil; -*-

* %i%?")))
```